# Validate numbers in /number/number/ format

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want to check is in string

```
/number/number/
```

or not, for example:

```
something/2018/02/something_else
```

How to check /2018/02/ is in string or not, I think with preg_match, but I don't know how.

My attempt:

```
$mystring = "something/2018/02/something_else";
preg_match("/[0-9]/[0-9]/",$mystring);
```

Comment: really not clear what you want, can you provide some concrete examples

Comment: Check is in string /number/number/ or not, for example my string: something/2018/02/something_else, so check /2018/02/ is or not

Comment: thats what you said in the question, simply repeating it does not help

Comment: @rtfm I guess he/she want to check url contain number(date) or not using preg_match()

Comment: I think use preg_match("/[0-9]/[0-9]/",$mystring), but not working

Comment: That's because you are using `/` as your delimiters and you aren't using quantifiers.  Always post your coding attempt in your question -- not as a comment.

Comment: Use `"~/[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/~"`

Comment: `strpos()` is more efficent for testing if a string is in a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pattern: `~/\d{4}/\d{2}/~`  [Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VACWif/1)

You need to use pattern delimiters (preferably delimiting characters that don't exist inside of your pattern -- to avoid unnecessary escaping).

You also need to tell the regex engine how many digits you expect to match.  This is done inside of curly brackets.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/OQpH1))

```
$mystring = "something/2018/02/something_else";
if(preg_match("~/\d{4}/\d{2}/~",$mystring,$out)){
    echo "Found: {$out[0]}";
}else{
    echo "Date components not found";
}
```

Output:

```
Found: /2018/02/
```